# How to conditionally render div elements in two columns

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm creating a modal and I have to render the following:
On the left side (in order):

1. A heading that says the maximum number of entries has been reached
2. heading that informs the user if any row contains and invalid name
3. heading that informs the user if any row contains and invalid sector

On the right side:

4. A save button

My div so far:

```
<div
  className="button"
  style={{
    marginTop: "50px",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  }}
>
  {
    /* point 1 */
    newCompanies.length === 10 && (
      <h3 class="maximum-message">
        Maximum number of companies: 10 reached
      </h3>
    )
  }
  {
    /* point 2 */
    (invalidNameIdx.length != 0) && (
      <h4>Please enter valid names</h4>
    )
  } 
  {
    /* point 3 */
    (invalidSectorIdx.length != 0) && (
      <h4>Please enter valid sector</h4>
    )
  }
  {/* save button */}
  <ModalSaveButton
    onClick={() => this.addCompany()}
  >
    Save
  </ModalSaveButton>
</div>
```

.css file:

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Instead how I want it to look is like this with two columns, one for the text and one for the button. The button also shouldn't swell up like it does for the top picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex-direction: column` on the outer div and then for the button add a style or className  to add css `align-self: flex-end` to get to the layout you want

```
<div
  className="button"
  style={{
    marginTop: "50px",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
  }}
>
  {
    /* point 1 */
    newCompanies.length === 10 && (
      <h3 class="maximum-message">
        Maximum number of companies: 10 reached
      </h3>
    )
  }
  {
    /* point 2 */
    (invalidNameIdx.length != 0) && (
      <h4>Please enter valid names</h4>
    )
  } 
  {
    /* point 3 */
    (invalidSectorIdx.length != 0) && (
      <h4>Please enter valid sector</h4>
    )
  }
  {/* save button */}
  <ModalSaveButton
    style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}
    onClick={() => this.addCompany()}
  >
    Save
  </ModalSaveButton>
</div>
```